# Compare strings in a column without considering character's order and if equal make them identical (same order) in R

Tags: r, string

My data frame has (8211 observation) but following is a simplified example. If I have the following data Frame in R

```
Var1  Freq
a/b/e 1 
b/a/e 2
a/c/d 3
d/c/a 1
```

How can I obtain the following data frame:

```
Var1    Freq
a/b/e   3
a/c/d   4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way

```
df1[, "Var1"] <- sapply(strsplit(df1$Var1, "/"), function(x) paste0(sort(x), collapse = "/"))
aggregate(Freq ~ Var1, df1, FUN = sum)
#   Var1 Freq
#1 a/b/e    3
#2 a/c/d    4
```

We use `strsplit` to split column `Var1` on `"/"`. This returns a list of character vectors which we `sort`, `paste` back together and later `aggregate`.

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(Var1 = c("a/b/e", "a/b/e", "a/c/d", "a/c/d"), 
    Freq = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L)), .Names = c("Var1", "Freq"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```